# base 64 image in MS-Word

Tags: html, ms-word, base64, ms-office, ckeditor4.x

I am uploading images in CKEditor and storing the image as a base 64 image and saving the file as a HTML generated DOC(using mso library). I am facing the issue in populating the image in MS-Word while image is populating well in other editors like open office. I have searched a lot on different discussion forums but hard luck. Please suggest some solution to showing the base 64 image in MS-Office or storing the image in some different format which can populate in MS-office. I don't want to store the image in server storage.

Comment: It's not clear what programming language is being used to "populate in MS-office"?

Comment: @CindyMeister.. Its java...

Comment: Not sure how java works - does it "automate" the Word application (work with Word's object model)? In any case, Microsoft Office doesn't support "streaming" content. The one exception is Word 2007 and later with the Word Open XML file format.

Comment: It would be necessary to "wrap" the image in valid Word Open XML, OPC flat file format. Then this can be written to the document using the `Range.InsertXML` method. For the basics see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml (just ignore that it discusses the JS APIs - the basic approach for creating the Word Open XML is the same)

Comment: @CindyMeister I can not save the doc in xml file format.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Word converts a *.doc into a *.docx when it opens it. And converts it back to *.doc when it closes the file. As long as it's open in Word it's possible to process the content as Word Open XML using Word's object library.